# PHP not matching loaded variable with $_POST?

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication, web

As the title states, I'm unable to match variable `$user` with variable `$_POST['username']`.

I've tried echoing the two variables, their outcome is exactly the same.

```
if ($user==$_POST["username"] ) {
echo"Sucessfully logged in as ".$user;
}
else{
echo'Unable to log you in!';
}
```

Not much more to say, really.

Comment: not enough code here. check for errors - *"Not much more to say, really."* - same here.

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($user, $_POST['username']);`. check what you are dealing with.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: That's about as in-depth as it gets. There's no more code that will help with the situation (I assume) $user is obtained by using fgets() once on a file with all of the userdata. No errors, either.

Comment: well, try all those "Try this" answers below. Edit: one down.

Comment: if $user is coming from a file it's probably got a \n or \r\n on the end that you're not seeing when you echo them

Comment: @RobGudgeon That's what I was thinking earlier, but OP didn't respond to Marc's comment, nor did they want to share the rest of their *relevant* code, nor any other information relevant to what their results were. There were a few answers who nailed it (one of which deleted; probably because they noticed they basically had the same answer). Marc's comment was indeed a good insight to see what the OP's results would be, and that in its own right, is worth its weight in gold ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try triming the strings :

```
if (trim($user) == trim($_POST["username"]) )
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped. If you want to see what it's for, go to http://www.lualessons.x10host.com .